# How to constrain axis-angle rotation?

Tags: unity, rotation, transformation, skeletal-animation, axis

I have a problem where I'm performing an axis-angle rotation and am trying to constrain my rotations.  Specifically I have a skeleton (model/mesh with rig, transforms are hierarchy parented to pelvis which move the triangles of the mesh) and I am constraining the motions to prevent bad joint rotations (e.g. knees bending sideways or backwards).  The rotations in this case can pretty much be constrained by saying "do not rotate about X/Y/Z."

I'm using the Unity3D RotateAround function which rotates about a specified axis at a point by an arbitrary angle.  Given control over this point, axis, and angle how can I constrain this rotation to prevent "bad" rotations?

Answer (score 1):

I spent a while chasing ways to change my problem to use Euler angles, but the easy solution was actually to just 0 the components of the axis I didn't want, i.e. (in C# Unity script)

```
Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(RD, RE);
axis.x = CanPitch() ? axis.x : 0.0f;
axis.y = CanYaw() ? axis.y : 0.0f;
axis.z = CanRoll() ? axis.z : 0.0f;
```

where RD and RE are Vector3's and CanRoll(), CanPitch(), and CanYaw() are functions that return a boolean value indicating if roll, pitch, and yaw are allowed on this joint (rotations about z, x, or y axes respectively).

This seems like a very obvious answer, but I spent awhile trying to verify that this actually does what I want.